# Spring Boot creates new instances for aliases in YAML configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, anchor, alias

When I load the following application.yaml, then the components and their relationship will be resolved, but instead of reusing the already existing instance a new comp1 will be created. When using standalone SnakeYAML, then the objects will correctly be reused.
I omitted the accessors for brevity in the code sample.

```yml
components:
  - &comp1
    name: comp1
  - &comp2
    name: comp2
    dependencies: [*comp1]
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "components")
public class ComponentConfiguration {
    private List<Component> components;
}

public class Component {
    private String name;
    private List<Component> dependencies;
}
```

So in the debugger I see:

```
components = {ArrayList} size = 2
  0 = {Component@0}
  1 = {Component@1}
    dependencies = {ArrayList} size = 1
      0 = {Component@2}
```

My aim is to have the correctly reused Component@0 as the dependency instead of the new instance Component@2.
How can this be achieved with Spring Boot and YAML?

Comment: I suppose it's related to Spring Boot flattening the HashMap returned by SnakeYAML. That way the references (i.e. aliases of anchors) will be lost as every definition will be transformed to a simple entry in a hashtable of properties :/